# What is the minimum value $P$ can have in $\cos(P\sin x) = \sin(P\cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the minimum value $P$  can have in $\cos(P \sin x) = \sin(P \cos x)$, if there is a solution to the above equation in $x \in [0, 2\pi] $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is in radians and I'm also going to find the minimum positive value of $P$. When $\cos x = \sin y = \cos (\pi/2 - y)$, we must have $$x - 2\pi k = \pi/2 - y$$ for some integer $k$.

In this case, we have $$P \sin x - 2\pi k = \pi/2 - P \cos x$$ Therefore, $P(\sin x + \cos x ) = \pi/2(1 + 4k) $. To minimize $P$, we may assume that $k = 0$ to minimize the RHS. Therefore, $$P(\sin x + \cos x ) = \pi/2$$ Now, we have that the maximum possible value of $\sin x + \cos x$ is $\sqrt 2 $ at $x = \pi/4$. Therefore, $$P = \dfrac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}} = \boxed{ \dfrac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}}$$ is the least value I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

If we take $P = \frac{4 \pi n - \pi}{2}$ for any integer $n$, we will have a solution at $x = \pi$.  We can check to see that for this $x$ and $P$, we have
$$
\cos(P \sin x) = \cos(0) = 1\\
\sin(P \cos x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi - 4 \pi n}{2}\right) = \sin(\pi/2) = 1
$$

So, there is nominimum such $P$.